# Watermarking for Spark structured streaming with three way joins

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have 3 streams of data: `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

There's a necessity to join these streams with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in a following chain: `foo -> bar -> baz`.

Here's an attempt to mimic these streams with built-in `rate` stream:

```
val rateStream = session.readStream
  .format("rate")
  .option("rowsPerSecond", 5)
  .option("numPartitions", 1)
  .load()

val fooStream = rateStream
  .select(col("value").as("fooId"), col("timestamp").as("fooTime"))

val barStream = rateStream
  .where(rand() < 0.5) // Introduce misses for ease of debugging
  .select(col("value").as("barId"), col("timestamp").as("barTime"))

val bazStream = rateStream
  .where(rand() < 0.5) // Introduce misses for ease of debugging
  .select(col("value").as("bazId"), col("timestamp").as("bazTime"))
```

That's the first approach to join all together these streams, with assumption that potential delays for `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are small (~ `5 seconds`):

```
val foobarStream = fooStream
  .withWatermark("fooTime", "5 seconds")
  .join(
    barStream.withWatermark("barTime", "5 seconds"),
    expr("""
       barId = fooId AND
       fooTime >= barTime AND
       fooTime <= barTime + interval 5 seconds
           """),
    joinType = "leftOuter"
  )

val foobarbazQuery = foobarStream
  .join(
    bazStream.withWatermark("bazTime", "5 seconds"),
    expr("""
      bazId = fooId AND
      bazTime >= fooTime AND
      bazTime <= fooTime + interval 5 seconds
         """),
    joinType = "leftOuter")
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
```

With setup from above, I'm able to observe following tuples of data:

- `(some_foo, some_bar, some_baz)`
- `(some_foo, some_bar, null)`

but still missing `(some_foo, null, some_baz)` and `(some_foo, null, null)`.

Any ideas, how to properly configure watermarks in order to get all combinations?

**UPDATE:**

After adding additional watermark for `foobarStream` surprisingly on `barTime`:

```
val foobarbazQuery = foobarStream
  .withWatermark("barTime", "1 minute")
  .join(/* ... */)`
```

I'm able to get this `(some_foo, null, some_baz)` combination, but still missing `(some_foo, null, null)`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving some information just for reference.

Chaining stream-stream joins doesn't work correctly because Spark only supports global watermark (instead of operator-wise watermark) which may lead to drop intermediate outputs between joins.

Apache Spark community indicated this issue and discussed while ago. Here's a link for more details: 
https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/cc6489a19316e7382661d305fabd8c21915e5faf6a928b4869ac2b4a@%3Cdev.spark.apache.org%3E

(Disclaimer: I'm the author initiated the mail thread.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! I wish this issue had been discovered much earlier, so I would not struggle that much during summer 2018 :)